# How to pass a function as a parameter in widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a widget and I want to pass a function to this widget, but when I try to do this I get this error.
[image]

Moreover when this function is passed to a widget it is automatically used, because it debugPrint "MONEY CHANGED".

This is the function code:

```
class Functions {
  changeMoney(int money) {
    Boxes.getCharacter().get(0)!.money =
        Boxes.getCharacter().get(0)!.money + money;
    debugPrint("MONEY CHANGED");
  }
}
```

And this is widget's code:

```
class DialogButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const DialogButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.answer,
      required this.function,
      required this.possible})
      : super(key: key);
  final String answer;
  final Function function;
  final bool possible;

  @override
  State<DialogButton> createState() => _DialogButtonState();
}

class _DialogButtonState extends State<DialogButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),
                widget.function
              },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              Text(
                widget.answer,
                style: rajdhaniStyle(weight: FontWeight.w600, size: 18),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

So the question is how should i correctly pass a function inside widget without automatically make it turn on the function and without getting an error?

Comment: this is because you call it that way: `function: changeMoney(...)` instead you should pass: `function: () => changeMoney(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also had to use .call after widget.function to use the function, but it seems to work! Thanks

Comment: just use `widget.function()` - not `widget.function.call()`

Comment: `.call()` is used only when your function can be null: `widget.function?.call()`

Comment: The thing is when I don't use .call() the function doesn't work

Comment: it is impossible: `widget.function() = widget.function.call()` - both versions do the same

Comment: The thing is that it isn't the same at least for me. For example I changed this function to return String and when I want to use it without .call() it doesn't return me String, but Function instead.

Comment: `onPressed: () => {` is wrong, I have no idea how it could work, it should be `onPressed: () {`

Comment: Same as before I have this error when I try to delete .call() - "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Result'.".  Result is my class which this function should return.
Also now even if I use .call() I get error "_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Result') " and there is no way function I created could return Null, because in every case there should be something returned.

Answer (score 0):

If the function have parameter, then the received widget (here is `DialogButton`) also need to declare parameter type. Example, the function is: `void doSomething(String hehe, int yolo) {}`. Then your `DialogButton` should be declare as `Function(String, int) onTap`.

More details, in first screen, you can call `DialogButton` like this:

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(...) {
    // do something
      DialogButton(
        answer: "your answer",
        function: (double money) {},
        possible: true,
      )
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to split/separate the function (not write-in-line like above), you could do as follow:

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(...) {
    // do something
      DialogButton(
        answer: "your answer",
        function: myFunction,
        possible: true,
      )
  }
  
  myFunction(double money) {}
}
```